# How I create an increment binary string in android

Tags: java, android, string, binary

I want to create an efficient function to increment an 8 bit binary string in android.Any idea?I have created this but is slow function...something better?

```
for(int b1=0;b1<256;b1++){

        String bin1 = Integer.toBinaryString(b1);

        long inb = Long.parseLong(bin1);

        String binfinal = String.format("%08d",inb);

                    text1.setText(binfinal);

                    String str1 =  binfinal.replace("1", "a");
            String str2 =  str1.replace("0", "_");

                    text2.setText(str2); 

}
```

Results: 00000000
         00000001
         00000010
         ........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for efficiency, its not going to get much faster than this...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){

            /* Print out the first 8 bits */
            /* For 16 bits, put this as the first line of the loop:
               for(int j = 32768; j > 0; j >>= 1)
            */
            for(int j=128; j > 0; j >>= 1){

                if((j & i) != 0)
                    System.out.print('1');
                else
                    System.out.print('0');

            }
            System.out.print(' ');
}
```

This will produce similar output, not positive if it meets your requirements.  This takes the value of i and converts it to a string.  Since i is being incremented by the loop, it acheives the same result as incrementing a binary string.

EDIT: Here it is with a string

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){

            String result = "";

            for(int j=128; j > 0; j >>= 1){

                if((j & i) != 0)
                    result += "1";
                else
                    result += "0";

            }
            // now do whatever you want with the String result
}
```

Comment: Then set j = 32768 to start the second for loop and adjust i accordingly.

Comment: Can you look my update code? I want string result to use it for other function...

Comment: Then instead of printing out the 1's and 0's, you need to add them to a String object and set that as the text.

Comment: Your example uses strings! Maybe you should read up more Java before attempting problems like these and asking for code.  I edited the answer to show it with a String.